# Make editable column in TableView

Tags: java, csv, javafx, tableview

I'm writing an Application that display a JavaFX table. Data to this table comes from .csv file. I'm trying to add editable column to displayed table, but I have no idea how to use .setOnEditCommit().
I have displayed table:

```
TableView<ObservableList<String>> dataTableView;
```

then adding a column:

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column new TableColumn<>("Set");
            column.setEditable(true);
            dataTableView.setEditable(true);
            column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

New, empty column is displayed, after double click I can add a some values, but after moving scrollbar this values disappear. I read that I must use .setOnEditCommit() with event. I tried do sth like this:

```
column.setOnEditCommit(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ObservableList<String>, String> t)->{

                t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setLastColumn(t.getNewValue());

            };
```

but this also failed, because I cannot define .setLastColumn(), couse my table is flexible, and always looks different becouse of diffrent csv files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks